# Как выводить посты в разную разметку wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать вывод постов с разной разметкой и разными классами?

```
<div>
  <div class='row-1 left'>
   <div class='left'> post 1 </div>
   <div class='center'> post 2 </div>
   <div class='right'> post 3 </div>
  </div>

  <div class='row-2 center'>
   <div class='left_1'> post 4 </div>
   <div class='center_1'> post 5 </div>
   <div class='right_1'> post 6 </div>
  </div>

 <div class='row-3 right'>
   <div class='left'> post 7 </div>
   <div class='center'> post 8 </div>
   <div class='right'> post 9 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо получить все посты в массив, а потом манипулировать этим массивом.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'post',
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

for ($i=0; $i < count($posts); $i+=9) {
    ?>
    <div>
        <div class='row-1 left'>
            <div class='left'><?php if ($i < count($posts)) { echo $posts[$i]->post_content; } ?></div>
            <div class='center'><?php if (($i + 1) < count($posts)) { echo $posts[$i + 1]->post_content; } ?></div>
            <div class='right'><?php if (($i + 2) < count($posts)) { echo $posts[$i + 2]->post_content; } ?></div>
        </div>

        <div class='row-2 center'>
            <div class='left_1'><?php if (($i + 3) < count($posts)) { echo $posts[$i + 3]->post_content; } ?></div>
            <div class='center_1'><?php if (($i + 4) < count($posts)) { echo $posts[$i + 4]->post_content; } ?></div>
            <div class='right_1'><?php if (($i + 5) < count($posts)) { echo $posts[$i + 5]->post_content; } ?></div>
        </div>

        <div class='row-3 right'>
            <div class='left'><?php if (($i + 6) < count($posts)) { echo $posts[$i + 6]->post_content; } ?></div>
            <div class='center'><?php if (($i + 7) < count($posts)) { echo $posts[$i + 7]->post_content; } ?></div>
            <div class='right'><?php if (($i + 8) < count($posts)) { echo $posts[$i + 8]->post_content; } ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php

}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Спасибо понял, но уже сделал как-то вот так http://s019.radikal.ru/i642/1704/e7/ea8e3739f30c.png  http://navatsof.vh91.hosterby.com/blog/

Comment: Вот интересно а можно ли как-то пропихнуть другую категорию в аргументы уже в цикле, например выводим посты из одной категории а потом идет if и изменение параметра массива категории, допустим на категорию 2, выодиться пост а потом опять измением параметры масива категории на те что были, другими словами изменить $args уже в цикле а потом на другой итерации вернуть на прежнее значение

Comment: Нет, конечно.Запрос к базе выполняется один раз, а в цикле WP выдает посты уже из памяти.