# Как в цикле get_posts() добавить разные классы блокам div

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть массив с названиями классов.

`$array = array("item-one", "item-two", "item-three", "item-four", "item-five");`

Как их добавить блокам выводимым циклом get_posts()?

`<div class="block__item item-one">`
`<div class="block__item item-two">`
и так далее...

```
<?php
global $post;
$array = array("item-one", "item-two", "item-three", "item-four", "item-five");
$myPosts = get_posts([
    'numberposts' => 5,
]);
if ($myPosts) {
    foreach ($myPosts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
         <div class="block__item">
           <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(
               'class' => 'block__icon'
           )); ?>
         </div>
        <?php
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Счетчик + остаток от деления на 4

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657000/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-wordpress?ysclid=lfl4jjjl70967107598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, что является результатом выполнения функции `get_posts` (не знаком с ВП). Но вижу, что скорее всего вы выводите 5 постов, при этом в массиве у вас 5 классов, тогда можно сделать так:

```
if ($myPosts) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($myPosts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
         <div class="block__item <?=$array[$i++]?>">
           <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(
               'class' => 'block__icon'
           )); ?>
         </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: "Сто" раз так делал НО... [$i] почему-то не хватило мозга добавить инкремент... Спасибо

Comment: ```get_posts()``` Получает записи (посты, страницы, вложения) из базы данных по указанным критериям.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="<?echo $className ?>">
```

Не знаю, что `get_posts` делает, но предположительно возвращает какой-то массив, предположительно длиной 5, как указано при вызове функции. Так что можно foreach на for заменить, и вместо $className  $array[$i] вставить